# Android LocalServiceSample missing detail

Tags: android, service

In the Android [LocalServiceSample](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) example, the `show_notification` method reads:

```
private void showNotification() {
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.local_service_started);

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, LocalServiceActivities.Controller.class), 0);
    ...
}
```

What is `LocalServiceActivities.Controller.class` referring to? I've searched the page for `LocalServiceActivities` but it's the only reference on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is LocalServiceActivities.Controller.class referring to?

Given the code snippet, it is an activity.

Code samples shown in the JavaDocs are almost always incomplete. In this case, we know that it is some activity because we are using `getActivity()` to create the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: I had guessed that as an option and tried substituting an Activity of mine, but then it didn't know what the `.Controller` referred to. So, I suppose that's closer to the root of my problem. Or is the 'LocalServiceActivities.Controller` actually just referring to the Activity?

Comment: @MikeT: For the syntax shown in the example code to be valid, `LocalServiceActivities.Controller` must be an `Activity`. `Controller` would be a `static` class, to make that work.